# Getting "Error: Invalid IdP response/credential" trying to add FB user on Firebase Auth list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, expo, facebook-authentication

I've been working on implementing Facebook & Google sign-in method in an app based on Expo.

Having Firebase connected with my app, I want the user to be listed in Firebase Users. While Google sign-in seems to work fine, Facebook gives an error as stated below from `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)`:

```
[Error: Invalid IdP response/credential: http://localhost?id_token=EAAGUBzIZAgb0BABAkdrj5NcUcvljcsLeNBQlV5VUZAZC7M8e7sSRg2MkqlFCuD7tKjin4uZBep5gSs20oAo8fXKiUqq2deEbUl6HoaAUskTda7x49VCqqcbYh1W3566fMZBtRFB5S3fRV7D41AGVGPMAck91l1KiFCzQzCGtSf5g6ZBKoyHw03LOVONcOiwVZB4vXVcGPYmIzL3RuzzztdBNLRql5ndSk0ZD&providerId=facebook.com]
```

Here's the **relevant part** of the code:

1. Firebase.js

```
// imports, configs and exports omitted
export const facebookProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
```

2. LoadingScreen.js (the sign-in part)

```
import firebase, { googleProvider, facebookProvider } from "../firebase";
import * as Facebook from "expo-facebook";

const LoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const signInWithFacebook = async () => {
    try {
      await Facebook.initializeAsync("444233602924989");
      const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
        "444233602924989",
        {
          permissions: ["public_profile", "email"]
        }
      );
      if (type === "success") {
        const credential = facebookProvider.credential(token);
        onSignInFB(credential);
      } else {
        Alert.alert('FB sign-in failed')
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      console.log(`Facebook 1 Error: ${message}`);
      Alert.alert(`first ${message}`);
    }
  };

  const onSignInFB = credential => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then(function() {
        navigation.navigate("Home");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
      });
  };
};
```

I've logged some of the elements as follows:

- While none of the error properties were available, the error code was `auth/internal-error`. Console.logging the error itself produced the error `Invalid IdP response/credential`.
- The token from `logInWithReadPermissionsAsync` was a valid access token (string)
- The `credential` from `facebookProvider.credential(token)` was:

```
    Object {"oauthIdToken": "EAAGUBzIZAgb0BAKgeMa5E7qHm8WNJYv5SeuQ8DHyhkUlAnkMhE7niu6tx3e2amSMHSEqG9B0MV4a9dygwgjs337PR7AA3M4PZB2F6x6n1FwAEyZBKhZBpOSE2OWQ9dJipirpafg61TKX36hnKIzaIcwRkjs8YYRBbDuLnZAhJzWst3ZBM5tafwxYKumv2F4kYdexxZAXqb1nosnwYodNvB9bstkcaBrfB8ZD",
      "providerId": "facebook.com",
      "signInMethod": "facebook.com",
    }
```

- `firebase.auth().currentUser` was `null`.

I've also gone through my own sanity checklist of possible mistakes below, but couldn't find any:

- FB is enabled in Firebase Auth Sign-in
- AppId & App Secret is correctly copied from FB app to Firebase(and also the redirect URI)
- Pass in the access token from `Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync` to Facebook's access token debugger and see if anything is wrong (e.g. expired or invalid)
- Check if an actual credential is returned from `facebookProvider.credential(token)` and passed to `signInWithCredential`

It would be great to find out the source of the problem! (one possibility might be the access token returned from `logInWithReadPermissionsAsync` is identical with the `oauthIdToken` property in the `credential` object, but I haven't manually put or changed any one of those.)

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I tried to use react-facebook-login and Facebook Javascript API. Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I banged my head against this today and the solution was to pass an object in to the `credential` call, even though the docs say to pass in a string. In addition, the object property needs to be keyed as `accessToken`.

So instead of:
`const credential = facebookProvider.credential(token);`

try:
`const credential = facebookProvider.credential({ accessToken: token });`

Based on the docs, I have no idea why that key is needed or why it has to be an object, but it worked in my case. Hope it helps!